# What does OP mean?

Tags: discussion

Obviously, it means the person asking the question, but what does the acronym actually stand for?

And, I apologize for not being able to find the answer.  If there is something I should have read that would have explained this, and possibly, other things, please point me in the right direction, and I will go read it...

Comment: '[How useful are “Here, say this instead” answers, when the OP isn't asking for them?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2894)' uses this abbreviation.

Comment: @Jasper Yes, I know.  The repeated use of OP on that very post is the reason I asked this question.  I could tell what it meant, but I could not for the life of me understand the acronym.  Thankfully, now, I have been put out of my misery.

Comment: The purposes of the comment were to let future readers of this thread know where "OP" is used like this, and to make the "Linked" questions (in the right column of this webpage) show a link to that question.

Comment: I hope this was just a minor inconvenience.  Being "put out of one's misery" is a euphemism for *coup de grâce* --  being killed to end one's suffering.

Comment: @Jasper Oh! Thank you for the explanation...  The first one about the 'linked' questions.   As to the second comment, yes, I know what it means, I was using it ironically. ;-)

Comment: This could even be moved to the main site, eh?

Comment: The information packaging tag gets two clandestine OPs. :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"OP" is short for "original post" or "original poster".

I make a point of spelling out abbreviations like this.  I also edit posts to spell out such abbreviations.

Comment: It may have a lot of abbreviations. 

1 operation; operative; operator.
2 opportunity.
3 opus.

Comment: @Idon'tknowwhoIam. OP may have many possible interpretations, but it only has two in this context.